# QMutexLocker, QMutex C2530 references must be initialized

Tags: c++, qt

I have `QMutex m_mutex;` as a private field in my class and I try to lock it using `QMutexLocker` from one of the methods but when I try to build it I get C2530 error.(My compiler is MSVC 2015).

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QMutexLocker>

class MyClass : public QObject
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}

    void setValue(const SomeEnum& val) 
    {
        QMutexLocker(&m_mutex) // C2530
        m_enum = val;
    }
private:
    QMutex m_mutex;
    SomeEnum m_enum;
};
```

EDIT: it works when I use `&this->m_mutex`

Comment: ***but when I try to build it I get C2530 error*** It would help your question if  you posted the exact text of the error message from the Output tab.

Comment: @drescherjm the exact error message is in the title. **error C2530: references must be initialized** the problem is solved by prepending `this->` but I don't understand why it doesn't work without `this->`, perhaps it's just MSVC error, they've changed a lot in their compiler since 2015... BR

Comment: Oh I see now. You want `QMutexLocker mylock(&m_mutex)` instead of `QMutexLocker(&m_mutex)`

Comment: @drescherjm yes, funny that I didn't see it. Thank you

Comment: I assume the real code has a semicolon on that line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code should be:

```
QMutexLocker something(&m_mutex);
```

which declares a variable called `something` which is a QMutexLocker, and persists until the end of the block (which is the end of the function in this case).

The code `QMutexLocker(&m_mutex);` is a slightly vexing parse - it fits the syntax for a reference declaration, i.e. it's the same as `QMutexLocker& m_mutex;` , which produces the error because references must be initialized.

The code `QMutexLocker(&this->m_mutex);` does not fit the syntax for a reference declaration, so you don't get that error.  However it creates a temporary `QMutexLocker` object which is then immediately destroyed. So , even though it does not give a compilation error, it probably doesn't do what you intended: the mutex will be locked and then unlocked before the next statement is executed.